# IBM BPM BPD import

Tags: ibm-bpm

I have got a process apllication which I exported from an env. and want to import it in another env. The hogher env. already has an older version of process application running. I could not find any option in Process center to update the process application. Whenever i try to import it, it says that the application already exist. Could anyone let  me know how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

On IBM BPM plateforme each application is defined by the prefix 
try first to edit the one you already have then import the new one and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Change the snapshot name , the server you want to import to has may already snapshot with the same name